# How to remove the calendar's default fields using C# code

Tags: web-part

I am creating a calendar list using code and I am adding my own columns to it. When I click "+Add" link to create a new calendar item I am able to view the custom fields along with the default calendar fields. So please tell me the code to remove/hide the calendar's default fields.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple code to hide `Location` field in default calendar content type:

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mysite"))
{
     using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
     {
          var list = web.GetList("http://mysite/Lists/MyCalendar");
          var contenttype = list.ContentTypes["Event"];
          contenttype.FieldLinks["Location"].Hidden = true;
          contenttype.Update();
     }
}
```